# Store custom data in SVG elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How can I store custom data in SVG elements?
For example I have this circle:

```
var circleData = [{ x: 40, y: 40, startX: 40, startY: 40}];
            var mycircle = assetGroup.append("circle").data(circleData).attr("class", "drag-circle").
                attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
                .attr("r", 8).attr("stroke", "#BBBBBB").attr("fill", "white")
                .call(this.circleDragDrop);
```

Yes, I'm saving startX/startY because I use these values after a failed drop action (not failed in "technical" way- more a "rule" violation) to move the circle back to its start point).

Worked fine until... now I have not only this circle but also a rect with similar behavior (drag and drop, data object with positions). When I change the data values on the rect it also overwrites the object in `data()` of the circle. 
Does `data()` always refer to a shared object? Is there an easy and nice way to safe such data as positions etc in a SVG element?

Comment: What's `assetGroup`? Does `assetGroup.append` return the appended element, or the `assetGroup` object? I assume the latter so you set the `data` property on the `assetGroup`, not the appended circle, then overwrite it when appending a rectangle.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that: assetGroup is a SVG "g" group. Before the code above I have something like:
var assetGroup = d3.select("#assets").append("g")

Comment: So, according to the docs,`.append` "Appends a new element with the specified name as the last child of each element in the current selection, **returning a new selection containing the appended elements**. Each **new element inherits the data of the current elements**, if any, in the same manner as select for subselections."

Comment: To sum it up, `selection.append(foo)` appends `foo` to the `selection` and *returns the selection*. Calling `.data(...)` on the returned selection updates its data, not data of any particular element. Maybe you could go around it using `assetGroup.data({ circle: circleData, rectangle : rectData })`?